# Java 8 update 5 rendering broken

Tags: java, gpu, nvidia

I just installed JDK 8 on my Win7 x64 optimus enabled notebook Intel HD 4000 + Nvidia 650M and Java rendering seems to be broken. I had no problem with JDK 7.

This is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: Did you reboot when the installation completed?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737535/swing-rendering-appears-broken-in-jdk-1-8-correct-in-jdk-1-7) seems to be a similar problem. Also note the marked answer which might be useful `Finally I found the solution for my problem. I had to change the energy control settings of my NVIDIA GeForce 620M to maximum performance.`

Comment: I done that but didn't help

Comment: I found solution, I changed my prefered GPU from Intel HD to Nvidia and now it seems everything works