# Why java swing gui is drawn bad?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Something strange with my java interface. It's drawn very bad.

[image]

[image]

What could be the problem?

Comment: *"What could be the problem?"*   nVidia graphics card.. the code..

Comment: @Mohit Its most probably not related to the code.May be some power optimization options in lappy would help.

Comment: @joeyrohan May be you are right. But we can not come to an answer on the basis of this snippet. right ?

Comment: At first I created gui in code and there was this problem. After that I decided to use some of form builder for eclipse. Now I use eclipse plugin called JFormDesigner but the problem has remained. So it's no code problem.

Comment: Thanks. Joey rohan's answer has solved the problem.

Comment: Probably more SO correct is to close this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This creates problem with JDK 8, which can be solved by changing your graphics card settings.

Source:
[Swing rendering appears broken in JDK 1.8, correct in JDK 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737535/swing-rendering-appears-broken-in-jdk-1-8-correct-in-jdk-1-7)