# JFrame pixelated components

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have created a Java GUI useing `java.swing`

When i run my program the UI is pixalated:

[image]

this is my Panel with all the componets:

```
public GuiPanel(){
    super();
    this.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10) );
    //Layout:
    GridBagLayout gridbag = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    this.setLayout(gridbag);
    setUpJButton();

    //textField
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    setUpTextField();
    c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    gridbag.setConstraints(textField, c);
    c.gridwidth = 1;//reset gridwidth
    this.add(textField);

    c.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 0, 0);//padding to top

    //anmelden Button
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
    setUpJButton();
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_START;
    this.add(logInButton, c);

    c.insets = new Insets(10, 5, 0, 0);//padding to left

    //abmelden Button
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_END;
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    this.add(logOutButton, c);
}
```

i've been googeling for hours but i didn't found a solution for this problem.

Comment: There are similar problem reported and I think the problem was caused by a driver issue. Upgrade if you can your drivers.

Comment: Duplicate [Swing rendering appears broken in JDK 1.8, correct in JDK 1.7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737535/swing-rendering-appears-broken-in-jdk-1-8-correct-in-jdk-1-7)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an OpenGL problem. Drawing of user interface components is usually done hardware accelerated. Specifically with OpenGL and DirectX in Java. You can try to

- update your driver
- try to fall back to software rendering by passing `-Dsun.java2d.opengl=false -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false` as command line option to the JVM.

You can find a whole list of options to control the rendering in Java2D in this article: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html