# How to fix blurry Swing elements in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I created a GUI with one JButton in it but it just shows a blurry button.

Here you see what I mean.

[image]

This is the code of my main class:

```
    Gui gui = new Gui();
    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gui.setSize(300,  300);
    gui.setVisible(true);
```

Code of gui class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
public class Gui extends JFrame {
    public Gui() {
        super("testing buttons");
        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JButton btnClickMe = new JButton("Click me");
        getContentPane().add(btnClickMe);
    }

}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I tried to add it but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: FYI when I run your code the button appears clearly with label "Click me"

Comment: Maybe try set the look and feel to the system look and feel.

Comment: I always get the blurry button :s Could it be the java version or something?

Comment: I don't think so. Is it only the buttons?

Comment: call the repaint() on the frame and see if its blurry

Comment: Only the buttons are blurry and repaint() doesn't have any effect.

Comment: @Grasshopper Did you try the system look and feel?

Comment: @Grasshopper Seems to be an issue with the energy control settings. [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737535/swing-rendering-appears-broken-in-jdk-1-8-correct-in-jdk-1-7)

Comment: @DimaMaligin Thank you so much! It works when I run Eclipse with my NVidia Graphic Card instead of my on board gpu. I didn't know how to search my problem on the web.

Comment: Make sure you UI is initialized and displayed within the context of the EDT, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to call

```
super("testing buttons");
```

To set the title, just use:

```
gui.setTitle("testing buttons");
```

What operating system are you running?

Comment: It's solved, the problem was that my onboard Intel graphics couldn't render buttons for some reason. Now I use my NVidia card and it works :)

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22737535/261156).