# Swing layout issue on migration to java 8

Tags: java, swing, java-8, rendering

My swing application in java 5 which had a display like

[image: this]

After migrating to java 8, zoomed up and displays only a part of it like
[image: this]

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737535/swing-rendering-appears-broken-in-jdk-1-8-correct-in-jdk-1-7) and tried setting J2D_D3D as environment variable and also tried passing it as a vm parameter. But didn't solved the issue. Any idea what this could be?

Comment: Could you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code example that illustrates your problem?

Comment: Was the migration from 6 to 8 or 7 to 8?

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to be able to help with this without an MCVE.  But you could possibly help track the problem down by seeing how the code behaves on Java 6 and Java 7 as well.

Comment: I will try and post an MCVE

Answer (score 3):

For reference, here's an example the *doesn't* have the problem. It uses a `GridLayout(0, 1)` with congruent gaps and border. Resize the enclosing frame to see the effect. Experiment with [`Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.html) as an alternative.

I suspect the original code (mis-)uses some combination of [`setXxxSize()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513) or [`setBounds()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html), which will display the effect shown if the chosen Look & Feel has different geometry specified by the buttons' UI delegate.

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31078625/230513 */
public class Buttons {

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Buttons");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 10, 10));
        p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            p.add(new JButton("Button " + (i + 1)));
        }
        f.add(p);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Buttons()::display);
    }
}
```