# Java swing not working in jdk1.8.0_51

Tags: java, swing, java-8, java-web-start

I am migrating an EAR application from `jdk1.7.0_67` to `jdk1.8.0_51`. Presentation tier is **Java swing** and business tier is **stateless EJB exposed as web service** and communication between presentation and business tiers is connected by **hessian protocol** and back end tier is **sybase**. Application server employed is `Wildfly 8.2.0` and am testing the application on `Windows 7` OS.

After I launch the swing application by **java webstart** by giving the JNLP URL in the browser, application gets launched and once I click any UI element in the application, application gets hanged and the related java console gets black completely. I could not find any logs in any layer and I am getting full response from the back end.

Are there any upgrade actions required for swing applications to work with jdk1.8.0_51.? JFYI that the application works perfectly fine with jdk1.7.0_67.

Can anybody please help me in resolving this issue and also let me know about the changes done in java swing in `jdk_1.8.0_51`.

Comment: *"..application gets hanged and the related java console gets black completely"*  So by 'java console' you mean [*this* Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml)?

Comment: Could be similar or same as issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737535/swing-rendering-appears-broken-in-jdk-1-8-correct-in-jdk-1-7

Comment: Do you have to force the application to stop, or does it crash and dies by itself at some point? Is the process using (a lot of) CPU/memory resources? Any chance you can run the app through a debugger?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson.. yes. it is the java console I mean. It is getting black completely after application gets hanged.

Comment: @Asakura.. I tried the environment variable J2D_D3D but did not work.

Comment: @ Eric.. yeah. Application has to be forced to stop. I increased memory to be utilized in jnlp but still same error. It works fine without any issues with 1.7. Just want to add that even with 1.8 (without java fx), it works fine. I verified with with a few initial versions of java 8.