# What is wrong with the display of a text in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I downloaded Android Studio, installed it, but text is shown incorrectly, as shown below:

[image: android_studio]

I use windows 7 and I don't have the same problem with eclipse, only Android Studio.
How to fix it?

Comment: May graphics problem in your PC. There is nothing wrong with android studio. I just installed yesterday

Comment: I found the similiar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737535/swing-rendering-appears-broken-in-jdk-1-8-correct-in-jdk-1-7

Comment: Try reinstalling Android Studio and restarting your system. Very unlikely its Android Studio's fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the decision of this problem.
Add environmental variable with name "J2D_D3D" and value "false", it works for me.
This decision from [Swing rendering appears broken in JDK 1.8, correct in JDK 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737535/swing-rendering-appears-broken-in-jdk-1-8-correct-in-jdk-1-7)