# White Blank Screen on Launching JMeter using Terminal on redhat

Tags: performance, terminal, jmeter, redhat, load-testing

I was getting a blank white screen when tried to launch jmeter version 3.3 using terminal,

1) Verified java version and it was 1.8: java -version

2) Increased JVM heap memory:
    export JVM_ARGS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m"

3) Done setting jmeter in path variable:
    export PATH=$PATH:/"Jmeter Folder path till bin directory",

4) jmeter [To launch the GUI]

```
      There is no error in terminal but still getting white screen as GUI after launching.
```

**Note**: I was able to run the jmeter scripts successfully using Non-GUI mode.

[image]

**log snippet:**

[image]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot and show jmeter.log ? what OS are you using ?

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK - I was using Redhat OS

Comment: Can you show jmeter.log ? Thanks

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK - Have added log snippet and there is no errors in the log.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not related to JMeter but to Swing and UI in your OS.

Have a look at :

- [Swing rendering appears broken in JDK 1.8, correct in JDK 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737535/swing-rendering-appears-broken-in-jdk-1-8-correct-in-jdk-1-7)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/22791235/460802
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/26610279/460802

Comment: I sensed one difference in terminal, Whenever we were getting the "White Screen" there is no "User Preferences" directory created. Do that make any sense?